Cut out harmonics that occur in the main signal
I have a signal like this:
The frequency I need is in the range of 5.5 kHz-6.5 kHz. I select the band I need, as Dan Boschen showed me in this answer.

And it all works, but I ran into a problem, as it seems to me, of harmonics. For example, if there is a signal with a large amplitude, say in the band 10.5 kHz-11.5 kHz (or 9.5 kHz-10.5 kHz), then its harmonics, as it seems to me, penetrate into my frequency band. And this happens only in the frequency range near the carrier. For example, if there is a signal at a frequency of 10.99 kHz, then I also see it in the 5.99 kHz range, only with a smaller amplitude, and in the 4.99 Hz range with an even smaller amplitude, etc. Moreover, the signal useful to me is also in the 5.99 kHz range and I do not understand how to get rid of the parasitic signal without touching the main one.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to combat it?
Below I will describe how the signal is processed:
Before the ADC there is a 4th order low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 15 kHz. The digitization frequency is 48 kHz.
Next, I multiply the input signal by cos(2πn6/48) and sin(2πn6/48), after which I pass the cosine and sine components through a 10th order low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 500 Hz.
Next, I shift the signal up and take the real part like this: LPcos(2πn6/48)* cos(2πn0.5/48)+ LPsin(2πn6/48)* sin(2πn0.5/48)
Then I denominate the signal to a frequency of 2 kHz and break the entire 1 kHz band into 100 Hz bands with ten BP filters and then in each band I build an envelope and look at the signal.

hi! Have you read the description of the [tag:dsp-core] tag? Please change your question to use more appropriate tagging :) Thanks!

I believe you are seeing the effects of aliasing. An anti-alias filter is required to select a band of interest and reject potential alias frequency zones prior to A/D conversion and similarly prior to any rate conversion.
If that isn’t clear, please update your question to include the sampling rate and specific processing and I can confirm that is the case (or not) and detail this further. Please show how you addressed the aliasing issues I raised in the link post including any testing of your actual filter performance to confirm the filtering required as described in that post is sufficient or if you are seeing the issue already identified in that post?

I have supplemented my question with the information you asked for.  If I missed anything, please let me know.

I tried to feed a signal from the generator and everything works fine. If I feed a signal in the frequency band 5.5 kHz-6.5 kHz I see and also if I feed a signal at other frequencies, it is completely suppressed. But as soon as I connect the microwave module to the input I see what I described above...

If you did the signal generator test as you described then this confirms the 10th order filter you have before the downsampler is doing it’s job (although from your description I don’t see any transition band described but it is implied that you are not going to get the full 1 KHz band, I assume you understand that). That said it seems the microwave output is not what you think it is. Have you measured that as well? Are the signal levels you are testing at with the signal generator indeed at the same levels as the microwaves? Be sure to look at the uW output over a much wider freq range too
